# Can AtomicInteger be used in a non-concurrent web application instead of integer?

Tags: java, atomicinteger

Would it make sense to use `AtomicInteger` in some arbitrary Java code instead of `Integer`? Even in a single-threaded context, where thread safety is not an issue?

Would that help with performance in any way?

Comment: Why do you think you won't be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, it can. There is no reason for it to not work.

Comment: Try it, TBH. Or if you're asking about performances, clarity or such, precise it in your question.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer, like - is something missing in order to get it accept-worthy?

Answer (score 2):

**No:** Integer is a somewhat *special* class. For example the compiler knows how to auto-box int to Integer and Integer to int.

**Yes:** both classes represent whole numbers. They both extend the Number class. So sure, you can use AtomicInteger as replacement for Integer.

But: keep in mind that `AtomicInteger` simply has special properties that normal Integers do not have. These special abilities do **not** come for free. So there is a <strike>potential</strike> **very real** performance penalty for blindly doing it.

And of course: you don't write source code because you *can*. You strive to write exactly that source code that is required to solve a certain problem. Meaning: you use int primitive types when you need them; you use Integer objects when you have to, you use AtomicInteger when the problem statement requires to do so.

In other words: when you go for duck hunting, you pick a shotgun. Of course, you could also use an *assault rifle* (both are guns in the end). It is just that different tools have different usage scenarios, and you pick that tool that *best* fits the job.

Beyond that, you get *performance* wrong. Completely wrong. Your comment implies that you think: "AtomicIntegers are mutable; Integers are not" ... so I guess your conclusion is: their performance is better.

What you are forgetting: they are not only mutable, they also guarantee **atomic** behavior. And guess how that is achieved: A) by using com.misc.Unsafe and B) `private volatile int value;`

Meaning: AtomicInteger has a **volatile** field. Each and any **update** is written to **main** memory. Do you have *any* idea how long writing to memory takes?!

Probably not - then let's see:

> L1 cache reference    1   second
>
> Branch mispredict     10  seconds
>
> L2 cache reference    14  seconds
>
> Main memory reference 3.3 minutes

( [source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cK52J6MQYV0fhlo3LDOB44b4o-IogE2z5tcOxyA-H4c/pub?gid=0) )

I only used the last column - which scales to human understandable measures.

Meaning: when going to the L1 cache would cost **1 second** - the table tells you that turning to memory costs **3 minutes**.

So your idea of *improving* performance by using that "mutable" class gives 180 times performance penalty.

Long story short:

- [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)
- when you think about performance - sorry, you have to understand the **full** stack, top to bottom

Long story short: one doesn't worry about performance until one has real issues (like testers/customers complaining at a function takes to much time). Then you start to investigate. You do **profiling** to understand what exactly causes the performance problem. Then you fix that. Of course, you avoid making outright stupid mistakes. In your case: when your program has to do so intensive computing on whole numbers that you worry about performance, the answer is simple: then you would use primitive type **int** values; and completely avoid reference type Integer objects in the first place.

Comment: AtomicInteger is mutable, and Integer is immutable. Shouldn't mutable objects perform faster!?